# Is there a way to export reports from Microsoft CRM4?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm setting up a proper dev environment for my client (dev/qa/stage/prod). I'd like to find a way to export reports so we can cleanly move from one environment to the next.  Custom RDL type reports are easy (just import the RDL in the next environment), but the reports that are built inside CRM don't appear to export anywhere.  Am I missing something?  Is this another feature that was missed?

Apperciate the help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For any report in CRM you can:

- Navigate to the reports grid
- Highlight the report you want
- Click Edit report
- Click Actions-> Download Report

This will give you the .rdl file. Why do you want to export and import native reports?

Comment: I'm rebuilding our development server.  I needed to move the reports that our BA had built in CRM so I could move them to the new dev server.

Comment: dumb question maybe but how do you "import" or upload the .rdl file then?

Answer (score 0):

The reports are stored in the CRM installation directory which will most likely be something like the following: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Reports\

Answer (score -1):

Go to reports.
Select the report and click 'edit report' in the toolbar
in actions click 'Download report' and you get a spiffy little RDL file to play with.